# Word or idiom for a small group of birds

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

Looking up online, I realized there are quite a few different words for groups of birds. For pigeons, a group would be a `flock` or a `flight`, while for falcons you would have a `cast` of falcons.

But, what about nouns that give some information on the number of birds? Is there, for instance, a word signifying `a small group of pigeons`? Or just a small group of birds.

Comment: The only generalized terms I have heard used are ***flock*** and ***voley***, only to describe a group of birds

Comment: Assuming your own search turned up no such specific word, you might want to use a word synonymous for "small group" or "few" to convey, in a singular word, the concept of a small group, then add "birds" or "pigeons".

Comment: *Flock* is used not only for birds but sheep and goats too.

Comment: Obviously, a *twitter* of birds.

Comment: Possible useful reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal

Comment: Flocklet.  Mini-flock.  Cohort.  Small band.

Comment: A **Modicum** of pigeons stuttered across the desultory sky.

Answer (score 5):

The word I would use is **covey.** As the following citation shows, **covey** can be used as a word for a small group of birds: [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/covey)

> a small flock of birds, especially partridge.

The same source gives many example sentences using *coveys*, meaning small flocks of birds, of which the following is one:

> ...both species form coveys, which are flocks of 4-6 fused family
>   groups.

Comment: That only works for grouse, partridges, and quail.

Comment: @Robbustocovey - definition of covey in English | Oxford Dictionaries
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/covey
a small flock of birds, especially partridge.(But the Collins English Dictionary  is on your side.)

Comment: BTW, the down-vote wasn't mine.

Comment: @Robusto -- I am new to SE -- and I still don't get anonymous downvotes. They do nothing constructive. Criticism works best with an explanation, imo.

Comment: @Robusto I had guessed that that wasn't your vote. I suppose the poster could wing it and go with the other answer, a detail, element or section of birds, but as I have already said I would use covey. OFF TOPIC My dog once startled a flock of indigo buntings, which flew up in a cloud of blue. We have the word, "murmuration," for the sound -I know you're going to tell me just starlings- but I don't know a word for the visual effect.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  I  think for the reason you gave is great! This why I think that the downvote should have been explained. Many of us are new here and we need to learn how to work within this community.

Comment: @Willow Rex Here are the two definitions my Random House College Dictionary gives for " smattering:" 1. A slight superficial or introductory knowledge of something 2. slight or superficial. So at least for people who use this dictionary, a "smattering" of pigeons is not an improvement on a "covey" of pigeons. By extension, you can talk about a smattering of flour or snow, but I don't think smattering is used as a counting noun.

Comment: @Airymouse, not sure if I am supposed to answer you. Thanks, I knew my suggestions had nothing to do with birds. I was wondering if OP would consider a different word set. I will try to remain strictly on topic until I understand this SE better.

Comment: Not going to downvote because I think the answer is spot-on and can easily be brought up to the standards of the site, but I'll withhold my upvote until it's got a definition added in (preferably with a decent dictionary source link and usage example, but don't strain yourself!).

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Removed downvote, added upvote, also did a few edits, which, if you don't like, you can roll back.

Comment: deleted obsolete comment, upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat whimsically, you could use the names of various subdivision of a military air force.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_force), for the U.S. Air Force, these subdivisions are:

- Detail (2-4)
- Element or Section (5-20)
- Flight (20-100)
- Squadron (100-300)
- Group (300-1,000)
- Wing (1,000–5000)

Comment: *Flight* is also used for birds, and not whimsically.

Comment: You could, but ELU is about accepted usage rather than DIY and confusing terminology.

Comment: I found somewhere "flight" being used for groups of pigeons. I just didn't know how large a flight was

Answer (score 0):

How about a smattering of pigeons or a sprinkle? These are synonyms of ['small number'](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/small%20number).